How to start Thunderbird on specific desktop
I start a number of applications when I log in, on different desktops. This works well, except that Thunderbird refuses to move from desktop 1. To do this, I have used the extension Auto Move Windows, but it won't move Thunderbird. Failing that, I later tried the more elaborate Smart Auto Move, but have never found a solution. The latter extension tries to autosave/automove everything, which is not what I want or need. I also find the documentation unclear. Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS + Gnome. Anyone?

Firstly, I think you are using the term desktop meaning workspace.
Although I have not used it myself you could try using devilspie
sudo apt update

sudo apt-get install devilspie 

devilspie is a non-gui utility that lets you make applications start in specified workplaces, in specified sizes and placements, minimized or maximized and much more based on simple config files.
(I believe there is a gui addon available.)
For more information see
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Devilspie

There is a windows equivalent called develspie2
Devilspie2 is a window-matching utility, allowing the user to perform scripted actions on windows as they are created. For example, you can script a terminal program to always be positioned at a specific screen position, or position a window on a specific workspace.
sudo apt update

sudo apt-get install devilspie2

for more information see
https://www.nongnu.org/devilspie2/

I'll give it a go tomorrow! ;)

Workspace is indeed correct.
